# How i can resume after error event in piped stream in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream

After i emit error event in MyWritableStream, data transmission stops. What i need to do to resume data transfer?

```
var readable = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');
var writable = new MyWritableStream();

writable.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    // How i can resume?
});

writable.on('finish', function(){
    console.log('finished');
})

readable.pipe(writable);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but you might wanna check out https://github.com/miraclx/xresilient

I built this for this exact same reason (works best with seekable streams).

You define a function that returns a readable stream, the library measures the number of bytes that have passed through until an error is met.

Once the readable stream encounters an `error` event, it recalls the defined function with the number of bytes read so you can index the stream source.

Example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const xresilient = require('xresilient');

const readable = xresilient(({bytesRead}) => {
  return generateSeekableStreamSomehow({start: bytesRead});
}, {retries: 5});

const writable = fs.createWriteStream('file.test');

readable.pipe(writable);
```

- File streams are indexable with the `start` option of the [fs.createReadStream()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) function.
- HTTP Requests are indexable with the [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) HTTP Header.

Check it out.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xresilient

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if it is a normal practice, but i can't see another solution for now & it works for me. If you can advise more accurate solution, please do it.

We can track readable stream instance using `pipe` event in writeable one:

```
function WriteableStream(options) {
    Writable.call(this, options);

    this.source = null;

    var instance = this;

    this.on('pipe', function(source){
        instance.source = source;
    });
}
util.inherits(WriteableStream, Writable);
```

So, when we emit error event, and readable stream is unpiped automatically, we can re-pipe it ourself:

```
WriteableStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    this.emit('error', new Error('test')); // unpipes readable
    done();
};

WriteableStream.prototype.resume = function() {
    this.source.pipe(this); // re-pipes readable
}
```

Finally, we will use it the following way:

```
var readable = fs.createReadStream(file);
var writeable = new WriteableStream();

writeable.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    writeable.resume();
});

readable.pipe(writeable);
```